# applicaition randomly crashes without giving any error, and without throwing a system ui error

Tags: android, firebase, crash, firebase-storage

I'm working on a health app application and it's been working fine, then it suddenly started to crash(without giving the message system UI has stopped), it just crashes and reopens, I've got no idea why this is happening, the only error I see in log chat or debugger is this:
`

```
`A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 17871 (app.com.health), pid 17871 (app.com.health)
```

and this one:

```
2021-05-13 23:51:03.352 31072-31465/? E/fb4a.FbnsAIDLClientManager: Fbns AIDL request got RemoteException
    android.os.RemoteException: AIDLService is not bound
        at X.0JL.call(Unknown Source:403)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2021-05-13 23:51:05.473 1535-1583/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 15044 [2021-05-13 21:51:05.472] FD count : 595, wdog_way : softdog
2021-05-13 23:51:07.584 3227-20426/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
2021-05-13 23:51:13.266 652-652/? E/audit: type=1400 audit(1620942673.254:296292): avc:  denied  { kill } for  pid=0 comm="swapper/7" capability=5  scontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=capability permissive=0 SEPF_SM-A115F_10_1021 audit_filtered`
```

and this:

```
2021-05-13 23:49:39.249 1535-1566/? E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
        at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateAllPhoneStateLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5856)
        at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.notePhoneSignalStrengthLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5888)
        at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.notePhoneSignalStrength(BatteryStatsService.java:747)
        at com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.broadcastSignalStrengthChanged(TelephonyRegistry.java:2262)
        at com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.notifySignalStrengthForPhoneId(TelephonyRegistry.java:1353)
        at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephonyRegistry$Stub.onTransact(ITelephonyRegistry.java:508)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
```

and some firebase firestore exception about storage, I really need help I don't know whats going on
`

Comment: At which particular line of code are yu getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5`?

Comment: @AlexMamo it doesnt show which line just shows multiple java lines that are not related o anything i wrote in my app, like'4600IOexception" or something like that